# How to find most visited pages in site collection using sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, web, analytics

I want to find 3 top most viewed pages in the entire site collection and display their page titles. Using Web analytics webpart, I got top most 10 pages URL. But i want the page title and the not URL. Is there anyway to do that?

Regards,
Raji

Answer (score 0):

This post(http://auditlogsp.codeplex.com/) can give you a reference. The solution can help us to log the source of SharePoint events , actually include the 'Viewing' action.You can store those information at an isolated database for analyzing the “top” reports.